# How do you programmatically put folder icons on the Finder sidebar, given that you have to use a custom icon for the folder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sidebar, finder

Am currently working on a project, and though I can add sidebar items by adding to the com.apple.sidebarlists.plist file then restarting Finder, I can't seem to know how to make the folder icons show up using its assigned custom icon.

Can anyone point me to a link or a solution that would make me do this? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no supported way to do this using pure Cocoa. Use the LSSharedFileList API, instead. It's the supported way to manage the sidebar lists, and you can provide a custom icon (as an IconRef from Icon Services) when you insert an item.

Comment: Is this API available when running in a sandbox?

Comment: @DavidKocher Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @dejuknow: wrong. You use com.apple.coreservices.sharedlileslistd.xpc service for that. Basically, you create an NSXPCServiceConnection, create an SFLListChange object with SFLListItem for the FileURL you add, w/bookmarkdata containing the icons property (or grab existing one with FsRef/UrlBookmarkData/whatever) then publish your change to the SFLList via the XPC service et voila. Read app sandboxing guide for details. Google for coreservices/sharedfileslist.framework headers (or dump them with nm/otool/classdump). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the icons but I add items to the sidebar using the `EBLaunchServices` wrapper which is available open source here:

https://github.com/Eric-Bro/EBLaunchServices

It is very easy to use. For instance to add a mounted OSXFUSE volume to the sidebar you call:

```
NSURL* volumeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/MyVolume"];
[EBLaunchServices addItemWithURL:volumeUrl toList:kLSSharedFileListFavoriteVolumes];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too stubborn to not do the obvious. I did:

```
[[NSWokspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:someIcon forFile:someFile options:0];
```

to set the image icon for the folder. I from then I did `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` `NSUserDefaults` appending, and restarted Finder through Apple Events. That made it all work.

Comment: Don’t do that. Do what Peter Hosey said. There is no good reason not to use the Launch Services API.

Comment: Mmmm NSWokspace... sounds delicious.