# Mount a ram drive on Mac OSx without it appearing on Finders sidebar

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, applescript

To mount my RAM drive I am using:

```
    diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RAM_Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://51200`
```

To hide it I'm using:

```
   chflags hidden /Volumes/RAM_Disk'
```

**However the ram drive still appears in Finder's sidebar.**

I do not want all the 'hard drives' not to be listed under devices in Finder's sidebar, just **this** particular RAM drive.  Manually one can just drag it off the sidebar **but** I need to do this programmatically preferably with Shell Bash and if not that then with applescript.

I have tried changing the com.apple.sidebarlists.plist but this doesn't help.

**I need this to work also in El Capitan.**

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16769092/2836621

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't know how I could implement that API into  my NodeJS project but think that it wouldn't work on El Captain as it looks like it makes the changes to the com.apple.sidebarlists.plist that I manually applied with out success.  I could me that I could change the visibility setting for the item entry. I shall try that out and post the result.
P.s. I did restart Finder.